# Persist line breaks from iOS app post to Facebook

Tags: facebook, newline

OMG, does anyone know how to include line breaks in Facebook posts?! At this point I'm assuming that Facebook is intentionally stripping them out. I have tried everything I can think of to create line breaks `(i.e., <br>, <p>, \n, \r, %0D, &#x0D;, &#13;)`. Nothing works : (

Answer (score 1):

Try `<center></center>`.  It used to work as a line break, but don't know if it still does.